# URL is not changing. After first time login, the page is redirected to T&C page to accept

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, cypress, chai

Login.spec.js

```
  it.only('TC02 - Login with valid data as reseller ', () => {
    const id = ut.record(testdata, 2);
    cy.login(id.username, id.password);
    cy.title().should('equal', 'Compass - Home');
    cy.visit('/users');
    cy.logout();
  });
```

LoginPage.js -> from POM folder

```
checkHome() {
  const path = '/license-agreement';

  cy.url().then(($url) => {
      if($url.includes(path)) {
          cy.log("Yes")
      } else  {
          cy.log("No")
      }
   })
}
```

After, login I am calling checkHome method to see if the page is redirected to home or agreement. If its on agreement page then I get accept button and click it.

But when I log url it outputs the previous page url.

Also, this is solved if I put wait in between. But I don't want to use wait and something dynamic solution to this

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you should find a way to avoid this type of conditional testing.

If you cannot then you may want to include the code that calls the `checkHome()` method. However, to avoid using `cy.wait()`, you can either add a `cy.location('pathname').should('include', '/commmon-path/')` if your url's are common for the home page or agreement or query a common element in both pages and append a should (ie `cy.get('.common-element-in-home-and-agreement').should('be.visible')`).

Answer (score 0):

To wait on the url, instead of `.then()` try using `should()` with a function to handle either/or, because should will retry until condition is satisfied

```js
cy.url().should( url => {

  // Assert the url is one of the two expected, retry until passes
  expect(url).to.satisfy(function(url) { 
    return url.includes('/license-agreement') || url.includes('/home')  
  })

  if (url.includes(path)) {
    cy.log("Yes")
  } else  {
    cy.log("No")
  }
})
```